# How localisation on IOS/Android store works

Tags: android, ios

I have a mobile app (IOS/Android) I would like to build and deploy it for both corresponding store and for many countries, each country has it's own config and params, the question is: if someone try to install the app(ios /android) version from store outside his origin country, he will get the app which is not adapted to his params and config when he comes back to his original country, do you have any suggestion ??

here is an example: user from Germany travel to France for 4 days, he installs the app in France it works fine, back to his country it works fine as well but with wrong params and config

Expected :if the german user travel outside his country and install the app, he always gets the german version of the app.

Comment: You should have only 1 binary of your app, and change your params according to device's current region settings.

Comment: thank you CZ54, the params it s internal to the code I mean some "calculation staff relative to each country"  is that possible to build one binary for many countries and change the visbility in appstore  in this case??

Answer (score 0):

Speaking for android: You should have one app for the whole world. If you need to have a specific version for certain countries, you should upload a different app for those countries and adjust the visibility settings in the play store. But this adds the problem you just mentioned.

Translation is handled by the resource folders in android. You can add different values, including strings, for each language. Android will automatically pick the language based on the users language settings. So even if a German user with German settings downloads an app in France, his app will still be in German the whole time unless he switches his devices language.

Comment: Thank you Alexander, there is no issue with the translation but, when I upload the app in different countries play store the visivility settings is managed globaly ?

Comment: You need to upload your app once for Android and once for iOS and it will be available in all countries. The you can decide if you want to not show them in certain countries globally. There is no need to upload apps multiple times for each country.

Answer (score 0):

I come across some interesting facts, first of all thank Alexander and CZ54, so here is it:

1. the localization will be based on ID store instead of the IP address
2. I will have one build for all the countries
3. Upload once for IOS and once for Android.